# caffe: sum of conv layer with a single filter

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I have a conv layer of dimension nXmx16x1 and another filter "F" of size nxmx1x1. how to sum F with every single filter of conv layer (dimension of result: nxmx16x1).

As far I know, eltwise would need both bottoms be exactly the same size (including the number of channel)

Comment: you want to *sum* or multiply? can you write an equation of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I need sum or average. I also updated dim of results. I need something like eltwise but it require 2 bottoms being the exact same dim (is not the case here- channel sizes are different)

Comment: So you want `out_m,n,i,0 <- in_m,n,i,0 + F_m,n,0,0` for `i=0..15`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for [`"Tile"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/tile.html) layer (works like [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab)'s [`repmat`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)). Tiling `"F"` along `axis: 2` 16 times will make `"F"` the same shape as the input, then you can use `"Eltwise"` layer:

```
layer {
  name: "tile_f"  
  type: "Tile"
  bottom: "F"    # input shape  n-c-h-w
  top: "tile_f"  # output shape n-c-16*h-w
  tile_param { axis: 2 tiles: 16 }  # tile along h-axis 16 times
}
# now you can eltwise!
layer {
  name: "sum_f"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "x"
  bottom: "tile_f"  # same shape as x!!
  top: "sum_f"
  eltwise_param { operation: SUM }
}
```